# Linked List Addresses are not in regular intervals

Tags: c++

I am trying to figure out how the newNode addresses change each iteration of appendNode. When I convert the addresses from hexadecimal to decimal I get the values 14683824, 14683848, 14685096. While the first two addresses seem to increase by 24 the third address increases by 1248. I can't figure out why this is occurring.

```
//Main Program
#include <iostream>
#include "numberList.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    numberList list;

    list.appendNode(2.5);
    list.appendNode(3.4);
    list.appendNode(5.6);


   // list.displayList();


    return 0;
}

//append.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "numberList.h"

using namespace std;

void numberList ::appendNode(double num)
{
   listNode *newNode;
   listNode *nodePtr;

   newNode = new listNode;
   newNode->value = num;
   newNode->next = nullptr;

   cout << newNode << endl; //The addresses of the newNode dont have even 
 intervals

   if(!head)
      {
       head = newNode;
      }
   else
   {
       nodePtr = head;

       while(nodePtr->next)
       {
           nodePtr = nodePtr->next;

       }
   }

}

//numberList.h
#ifndef APPENDNODE_NUMBERLIST_H
#define APPENDNODE_NUMBERLIST_H

class numberList
{
private:
    struct listNode
    {
        double value;
        struct listNode *next;
    };

    listNode *head;

public:
    numberList()
    {
        head = nullptr;
    }
   //~numberList();
    void appendNode(double);
    void displayList() const;
    void insertNode(double);
    void deleteNode(double);

};
#endif //APPENDNODE_NUMBERLIST_H
```

Output:

0xe00eb0
0xe00ec8
0xe013a8

Comment: Linked lists are not guaranteed to have regular intervals. Each time you allocate a node for your list using new() operator the operating system will decide of its address.

Comment: You don't have enough code for a relevant answer, however if you use the `new` it doesn't guarantee you sequential addresses. Actuality, it's surprising they are that close. This is one of the reasons list is a cache-u friendly data structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard doesn't give you any guarantees about the location of memory you allocate. `new` could give you locations that are right next to each other, but it'd also be allowed to give you locations on a completely random basis. What specifically you end up with depends on

- The algorithm used for allocation by `new`
- The pattern of previous allocations

**So why did it happen this time?** In general, it makes sense for successive allocations to end up close together because that decreases the chance of a cache miss, but `new` has no obligation to do that. In fact, because `new` occasionally has to request memory from the operating system, and because `new` has to use a bit of memory to keep track of what's been allocated, **it's not possible to guarantee that all allocations happen at regular intervals.**

Comment: Thank you, that makes more sense now.